# Python store cv image in mongodb gridfs

Tags: python, mongodb, numpy, gridfs

For testing, we want to store our labeled image date into a mongodb database.

At a certain point in our image pipeline we have our labeled image as a openCV image, which is represented as a numpy ndarray.

How is it possible to store the image? As the images are relatively huge, we considered to use Gridfs.

Our simple code so far:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
import gridfs
import cv2

# access our image collection
client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
db = client['testDatabaseONE']
testCollection = db['myImageCollection']

fs = gridfs.GridFS(db)

# read the image and convert it to RGB
image = cv2.imread('./testImage.jpg')
image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

# store the image
imageID = fs.put(image)

# create our image meta data
meta = {
    'imageID': imageID,
    'name': 'testImage1'
}

# insert the meta data
testCollection.insert_one(meta)
```

Sadly *imageID = fs.put(image)* throws this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/gridfs/grid_file.py", line
>   337, in write
>       read = data.read AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'read'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/home/johann/PycharmProjects/mongoTesting/mongoTesting.py", line 17,
>   in 
>       imageID = fs.put(image)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/gridfs/**init**.py", line 121,
>   in put
>       grid_file.write(data)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/gridfs/grid_file.py", line
>   341, in write
>       raise TypeError("can only write strings or file-like objects") TypeError: can only write strings or file-like objects

Any hints or ideas how to store the images using gridfs, or is there any better way?

Comment: Hey did you try using numpy.array2string? https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array2string.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue by converting the ndarray to string.

**Store a new image with its meta data into the database:**

```
# convert ndarray to string
imageString = image.tostring()

# store the image
imageID = fs.put(imageString, encoding='utf-8')

# create our image meta data
meta = {
    'name': 'myTestSet',
    'images': [
        {
            'imageID': imageID,
            'shape': image.shape,
            'dtype': str(image.dtype)
        }
    ]
}

# insert the meta data
testCollection.insert_one(meta)
```

**Get the image back:**

```
# get the image meta data
image = testCollection.find_one({'name': 'myTestSet'})['images'][0]

# get the image from gridfs
gOut = fs.get(image['imageID'])

# convert bytes to ndarray
img = np.frombuffer(gOut.read(), dtype=np.uint8)

# reshape to match the image size
img = np.reshape(img, image['shape'])
```

Answer (score 1):

It is obvious that the problem is not related to the image size. There are 2 exceptions, we need  to solve the first one first.

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/gridfs/grid_file.py", line 337, in write read = data.read AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'read'

Please, check the file grid_file.py", line 337. There is no method for numpy.ndarray called read. To read from this data array you just need to slice what you want, for example:

```
b = np.fromfunction(f,(5,4),dtype=int)
>>> b
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [10, 11, 12, 13],
       [20, 21, 22, 23],
       [30, 31, 32, 33],
       [40, 41, 42, 43]])

>>> b[0:5, 1]  # each row in the second column of b
array([ 1, 11, 21, 31, 41])
```

Comment: As we want to save the whole image, I think slicing is not the way to go.

Comment: In that case just slice the whole rows and columns such as,
a=np.arange(15).reshape(3, 5) and b = a[:,:]. You can also use b=a.data which uses a pointer, but that would be more different to handle the data.